# i cant write 100 fibonacci series numbers

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int n,k;
long long  int aray[101];

printf("Enter the number range:\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
aray[0]=-1;
aray[1]=1;
printf("\n FIBONACCI SERIES: \n");
for(k=2;k<=n+1;k++){
aray[k]=aray[k-1]+aray[k-2];
printf(" %lld\n",aray[k]);
}return 0;}
```

hey guys I have some issues i wanna write first 100 number but it is broken after 92. number and i cant understand why can u tell me how can fix this and why series starting with 0 ? thanks

Comment: It’s starting with 0 because you are adding -1, that is not a fibonacci number.

Comment: The 100th Fibonacci number is too large to store in a 64-bit integer. Use a big math library

Comment: can u tell me which math library is big

Comment: The 100th Fibonacci number is 218,922,995,834,555,169,026.  That's too big even for a 64-bit `unsigned long long` in C.

Comment: Please elaborate ' is broken after 92'. Please read [mcve] for more information. And please fix the indentation of your code to make it more readable.

Comment: @ÖmerSertkaya: You cannot ask for a library recommendation here, even in comments. Use Google, Bing or any internet search tool to search for *C BigInteger library* instead.

Comment: @Fredrik thanks bro for helping and werner i am not good using english sorry for my mistake . i think this form is a programmer from not english grammar language :)

Comment: OT: properly formatting your code would be a good idea.

Comment: @ÖmerSertkaya It seems that 92 is the biggest fibonacci number that can be stored in an object of the type long long int.  If you change the type of the array to the type unsigned long long int and will use the conversion specifier %llu in a call of printf then if I am not mistaken the maximum fibonacci number will be 96.